# Filtering django querysets

Tags: python, django, web, search, django-views

In a project I have a view which displays in the browser as a searchbar to search recipes. I think there is a better way then how I'm doing it right now, but have no idea how. If I don't do what I'm doing right now, I get the error that you can't filter with None.

I know I could use a try except but then none of the values may be None or an error is raised.

```
class SearchResultListViewOther(ListView):
    model = Recipe
    template_name = 'recipes/search_other.html'
    extra_context = {
        'time': time,
        'categorie': categorie,
        'continent': continent,
    }

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Filter out recipes by some other params like the title
        """
        # Can not filter on None so set a value if no search params were given
        title = self.request.GET.get('title')
        if not title:
            title = '0'
        time_recipe = self.request.GET.get('time')
        if not time_recipe:
            time_recipe = 0
        continent_recipe = self.request.GET.get('continent')
        if not continent_recipe:
            continent_recipe = '0'
        object_list = Recipe.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=title) | Q(time__lte=time_recipe) |
            Q(continent__exact=continent_recipe)
            )
        return object_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain `Q` queries using the `&=` and `|=` operations.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Filter out recipes by some other params like the title
    """
    title = self.request.GET.get('title')
    time_recipe = self.request.GET.get('time')
    continent_recipe = self.request.GET.get('continent')

    # default empty query
    q = Q()
    if title:
        q |= Q(title__icontains=title)
    if time_recipe:
        q |= Q(time__lte=time_recipe)
    if continent_recipe:
        q |= Q(continent__exact=continent_recipe)
    return  Recipe.objects.filter(q)
```

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem ;)

Comment: Great solution man, now my code does not look that stupid jaja thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Filter out recipes by some other params like the title
    """
    # Can not filter on None so set a value if no search params were given
    title = self.request.GET.get('title')
    time_recipe = self.request.GET.get('time')
    continent_recipe = self.request.GET.get('continent')
    if title or time_recipe or continent_recipe:
        return  Recipe.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=title) | Q(time__lte=time_recipe) |
        Q(continent__exact=continent_recipe)
        )
```

Please try this.

Comment: Don't you need to use if _ and _ and _: since none of them can be None?

Comment: if we use `and` it will fail if title is `None` but time_recipe isn't.

Comment: This does not work as a solution for my problem. Because here still it is possible that title, time_recipe or continent_recipe gets in tho the if with the value of None. In this case only one has to be present